# Present UIImagePickerController from pagesheet modal jumps layout iOS 12

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, ios12

When present the iOS UIImagePickerController from an Pagesheet Modal in iOS 12, the modal jumps to the left top of the screen. When cancelling or taking a photo, the modal layout jumps back to it's original position. This problem started since iOS 12.

Does anyone have a fix for this problem? Or knows what this problem causes?

Before taking a photo:
[image: Before taking a photo]

When taking a photo (when UIImagePickerController showed):
[image: When taking a photo]

Comment: You can show some partial code about invoking `UIImagePickerController` ,that will be helpful.

Comment: Demo created in xcode: https://www.dropbox.com/s/za7odihoxrcp2vb/ImagePickerModal-Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: Thanks.Native code works fine in phone,maybe there have some code changed in pad.

Comment: Please check on iPad, there you see the issue. I have contacted Apple about this, they are looking into it. Let you know when there is an update on this.